# Unable to Map Picture to AD thumbnailPhoto in SharePoint 2013 User Profile

Tags: sharepoint, user-profile, sharepoint-userprofile

I'm not able to Map Picture to AD thumbnailPhoto in SharePoint 2013 User Profile:

- My current user have a Farm Permissions
- I'm able to edit picture in Manage User Properties
- When I choose thumbnailPhoto from drop down list and click OK, it returns back to Manage User Properties without mapping

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it is working, it was a very stupid actually, I was not clicking on ADD button before OK !!! , stupid isn't :) ?

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen after choosing thumbnailPhoto and then clicking "import"?

Or after it shows the property mapping for synchronization and then clicking on "OK"?

If none of your images have pulled through after mapping then try running this script:

```
$mySitesUrl = “http://mySiteURL”
$mySitesHost = Get-SPSite –Identity $mySitesUrl
Update-SPProfilePhotoStore –MySiteHostLocation $mySitesHost
–CreateThumbnailsForImportedPhotos $true
```

This article should help: [Adding Pictures to Active Directory and Show in SharePoint 2013](http://blog.blumshapiro.com/blog/2013/05/13/adding-pictures-to-active-directory-and-show-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: Actually I'm not able to map the attribute, not syncing. after open Picture property and select thumbnailPhoto and click OK, it is not mapping and keeps empty

Comment: Which browser are you using? Did you try it in both IE and Chrome? The UPS is setup correctly and the related services are running?

Comment: Thanks for your reply

- I'm using IE
- UPS is syncing correctly
- All services are running

Comment: Came across this site: [How to change user profile properties with PowerShell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chadray/archive/2011/12/06/how-to-change-user-profile-properties-with-powershell.aspx). Try update the property using PowerShell.

Comment: I tried following code with no success

`$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite http://CAHostURL

$context = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext]::GetContext($site)

$configManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileConfigManager $context

$UPAConnMgr = $configManager.ConnectionManager

$Connection = ($UPAConnMgr | select -First 1)


if ($Connection.Type -eq "ActiveDirectory"){

    $Connection.PropertyMapping.AddNewMapping("User", "Picture", "thumbnailPhoto")
}`

Comment: Do you get any errors when executing the script? Double check that you have values in each variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64925/discussion-between-ahmed-rabee-and-vince2322589).